# How to complete matrix multiplication with an index that runs across all nodes?

Tags: r, matrix

Not sure if this would be the right place to ask...but I am attempting to calculate a topological overlap measure (TOM) matrix  using R. I'm running into a problem with a likely simple solution.

Basically, I am not sure how to interpret the matrix notation for the TOM matrix. An example would be:

$l_{ij}=\sum_{u}a_{iu}a_{uj}$ where the index u runs across all nodes.

Would this mean I am multiplying entire rows by entire columns, and then finding the sum of these multiplications?

Comment: Letting $\mathbb{A} = (a_{ij}),$ this sum gives the components of $\mathbb{A}^2$, written in `R` as `a %*% a`.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198257/intuition-for-the-product-of-vector-and-matrices-xtax/198280#198280